# Combine text from 2 Text widgets in TKInter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have 2 text widgets (tkinter). But when i get text from both and try to write it into txt file in one line, it writes on two line(from 1st widget and then from second)
here is code:

```
def makeIt():
    s = facttext.get("1.0", END)
    count = counttext.get("1.0")
    final = "<string name=\"fact" + count + "\">" + s + "</string>"
    easygui.msgbox(final, title="olol")
    with open("text.txt", 'a') as out_file:
        out_file.write(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter automatically appends a newline at the end of the text widget. When you use the index `END`, you get this automatic newline. To get precisely the data that the user entered, use "end-1c" ("end", minus one character):

```
s = facttext.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input to the text widgets is coming from a user, and those inputs must fit on a single line in a file, then you should sanitise those inputs.

```
text widget.get('1.0','end').replace('/n','')
```